# How fix an error when import class to be used on Jest with React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I begin to use Jest with my ReactJs app.

I just follow the tutorial that shows the code below and it works for me.

sum.js file

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

sum.test.js

```
const sum = require('./sum');
test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

But now I want to test some methods that I created.

I try to test a function that I create in the file QuizzesHelper.js

```
export function setTextoNPS(valorNPS){
   ...
}
```

I try to import that way

```
import * as QuizzesHelper from '../../../components/Controller/QuizzesHelper';
```

I use the code above on my app and it works perfectly for me, but when I try to use it on my Jest test, it fails and shows me the error:

F:\Puc\RelatorioCanvas\reactJs_graduacao_mobile_first\src\components\Controller\QuizzesHelper\index.test.js:1

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import * as QuizzesHelper from '../../../components/Controller/QuizzesHelper';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1260:14)
```

How can I fix that error?

How to fix an error when import class to be used on Jest with React

Comment: Looks like your tests aren't getting transpiled, maybe the [jest babel](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel) configuration will help. Can you share your `package.json` and `.babelrec` or config json file?

Comment: You can see my package.json in https://jsfiddle.net/fabiobh/k9tpj2uv/4/ , I don't have a .babelrec file. I just install Jest using npm I jest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the tutorial on https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react
But instead of using yarn, I use NPM to install some Jest dependencies and it works for me now.
I run the following command to install jest using NPM

```
npm install --save-dev jest babel-jest @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react react-test-renderer
```